# Getting type error when using lodash's curryRight with mapValues

Tags: typescript, lodash, currying

I am trying to create a curried function of Lodash's `mapValues`.

```
const curried = curryRight<{ foo: string }, { foo: boolean }>(mapValues)(value => !!value);

curried({ foo: 'bar' }); // { foo: true }
curried({ foo: '' }); // { foo: false }
```

The function works but I do not know how to fix the type error:

```
Argument of type '(value: string) => boolean' is not assignable
to parameter of type '{ foo: string }'. (tsserver 2345)
```

[Here is the type for `curryRight`.](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/a83d860873a3ca5d8bde53432560c23b5b9da180/types/lodash/common/function.d.ts#L321)

```
interface CurryRight {
        <T1, R>(func: (t1: T1) => R, arity?: number): RightCurriedFunction1<T1, R>;
        <T1, T2, R>(func: (t1: T1, t2: T2) => R, arity?: number): RightCurriedFunction2<T1, T2, R>;
        <T1, T2, T3, R>(func: (t1: T1, t2: T2, t3: T3) => R, arity?: number): RightCurriedFunction3<T1, T2, T3, R>;
        <T1, T2, T3, T4, R>(func: (t1: T1, t2: T2, t3: T3, t4: T4) => R, arity?: number): RightCurriedFunction4<T1, T2, T3, T4, R>;
        <T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, R>(func: (t1: T1, t2: T2, t3: T3, t4: T4, t5: T5) => R, arity?: number): RightCurriedFunction5<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, R>;
        (func: (...args: any[]) => any, arity?: number): (...args: any[]) => any;
        placeholder: __;
    }
```

Considering the arity of `mapValue`, this should be the type that I am dealing with:

```
<T1, R>(func: (t1: T1) => R, arity?: number): RightCurriedFunction1<T1, R>;
```

Is there a way to type with out casting?